# Ajax URL not working when SEF settings is ON in Global configuration of Joomla

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-sef-urls

I am passing my data through `JQuery.post` method in my file. Its working successfully when "Search Engine Friendly URLs" and "Use URL rewriting" is OFF on server in Joomla 2.5 but when both settings is ON then url of `JQuery.post` is getting changed and not working properly.

```
jQuery.post('index.php?option=com_requests&controller=dashboard&task=messagesendtocook&format=raw&tmpl=component', { 
    replymessage:replymessage,fromid:fromido,msdid:msdido,refid:refido}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
        setTimeout( 'reload_parent_window();', 2000 );  
        window.parent.SqueezeBox.close();
});
```

My URL parameter when `SEO` settings is OFF

```
index.php?option=com_requests&controller=dashboard&task=messagesendtocook
```

which run successfully.

My URL parameter when `SEO` settings is ON

```
index.php/component/requests/index.php?option=com_requests&controller=dashboard&task=messagesendtocook
```

which is not running.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Juri::root()` with url.
So the code would be-

```
jQuery.post('<?php echo Juri::root()?>index.php?option=com_requests&controller=dashboard&task=messagesendtocook&format=raw&tmpl=component', { 
    replymessage:replymessage,fromid:fromido,msdid:msdido,refid:refido}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
        setTimeout( 'reload_parent_window();', 2000 );  
        window.parent.SqueezeBox.close();
});
```

Comment: @user2841211 : Is url same as before?

Answer (score 0):

I found that just adding a leading `/` to the URL worked the same, turning it into:

```
'/index.php?option=com_requests&controller=dashboard&task=messagesendtocook&format=raw&tmpl=component'
```